# How can I fix a class not found after composer update in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, class, error-handling, composer-php

I made a `composer update` and since then I get an error message:

> Class "Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Naming\UniqidNamer" not found
>   while loading "App\Controller\myApp\OriginalNameNamer".

And I just cannot figure out to fix it.
I made again `composer install`, and also composer `dumpautoload` but nothing helps

Everything was fine until I made composer update..

Comment: please check your composer.lock
the file is there:
https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Uploader/Naming/UniqidNamer.php
so might be you accidentally removed it from autoloader.

check your composer lock for this package and add to the question the version you're using.

Comment: I checked composer.lock and I cannot find it there

Comment: then it might be some other package dependency stopped this package from being installed. can you share your composer.json so I can try ?

Comment: my composer.json: https://codeshare.io/5NqRLV

Comment: If that class is needed, why not require it through Composer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your composer.json the class is missing from your project completely. It could be that it was dependency of some other package before, but now isn't.
However, the fact you're using dependency in your code doesn't make composer install it.
Simply run

```
composer require oneup/uploader-bundle
```

and it will be back in your project

Comment: Thank you! This error seems to be fixed, I get unfortunately now another error `Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\myApp\myController": argument "$mySystem" of method "__construct()" has type "League\Flysystem\FilesystemInterface" but this class was not found.

Comment: Do you think I need to do the same `composer require FilesystemInterface`?

Comment: seems yet another code you're missing: run
`composer require league/flysystem`

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately this time the error stays

Comment: please share the code of the faulty controller in the separate SO question I'll try to help when I see it ;)

Comment: I made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577020/how-can-i-restore-a-service-after-composer-update-in-symfony